# Why won't the Javascript in my script tags work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mp3

I learning javascript, and practicing with event handlers.
I've written the correct code (Im sure...) to make an mp3 play when a button (button1) is clicked.

I tried putting the code in the beginning.
I've tested to see if I typed in the right path for the mp3.
I've tried deleting the sort of irrelevent 2 lines of event handlers in the middle of the script.
I don't know what is going on! Can someone help?

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div><button id="button1" onclick="playMusic()">MUSIC</button>
<span><button id="button2">VIDEOS</button></span>
<span><button id="button3">PICTURES</button></span></div>
<div><button id="button4">BRAIN GAMES</button>
<span><button id="button5"><a 
href="C:\Users\sared\Documents\Vegas\message.html">TALK TO FAMILY</a> 
</button></span>
<span><button id="button6">STORIES</button></span></div>


<script>

    var item = document.getElementById("button1");
    var music = new Audio("C:\Users\sared\Documents\baccara.mp3");

    item.addEventListener("click", playMusic, false);
    item.addEventListener("dblclick", stopMusic, false);

    function playMusic() {
       music.play();
    }

    function stopMusic() {
       music.stop();
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Always check your browser console for errors before asking why things aren't working. `var music = new Audio("C:\Users\sared\Documents\baccara.mp3");` is definitely wrong, single backslashes before non-escape characters will just be ignored, and JS can't access the filesystem like that anyway

Comment: I love you!! Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslashes - `\` will break your file paths. Change `\` to `\\`, and it should work. Keep in mind that JavaScript can't normally access the local file system like this though.

```
<a href="C:\Users\\sared\\Documents\\Vegas\\message.html">TALK TO FAMILY</a>
```

JS:

```
var music = new Audio("C:\Users\\sared\\Documents\\baccara.mp3");
```

Comment: Depending on the resource, you could use `file:///C:/Users/sared/Documents/baccara.mp3`.